# My function doesn't modify the array

Tags: php, arrays, function, indexing

I have written a function that shifts array values one index to the left. It looks like this:

```
function index_shift($array, $index){
    $n = count($array) - 1;
    for($i = $n; $i >= $index; $i --){
        $array[$i + 1] = $array[$i];
    }
    print_r($array);
}
$array_one = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");

index_shift($array_one, 3);
echo "<br />";
print_r($array_one);
```

I inserted the first `print_r` into the function to see if it works. It does, it shows that the values have been shifted to the left (`d` is on the 4th and 5th index, all the values are moved). But the second `print_r` outside the function shows that the array is not modified. Seems like the function works as it has to, but it doesn't modify the array. Maybe I should use a **`&`** somewhere?

Comment: You seem to already know the problem and the answer...

Comment: Yeah, well I am a total beginner I had no idea where to use that damn sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an array. If you want to modify the array itself you need to pass the reference to the array:

```
function index_shift(&$array, $index){
    $n = count($array) - 1;
    for($i = $n; $i >= $index; $i --){
        $array[$i + 1] = $array[$i];
    }
    print_r($array);
}
```

Here is a link about reference passing using &: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: It works! I knew I had to use that sign somewhere, wasn't sure where. Gonna accept that answer as soon as the system lets me do so. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can return the array value back to the function call:

```
function index_shift($array, $index){
    $n = count($array) - 1;
    for($i = $n; $i >= $index; $i --){
        $array[$i + 1] = $array[$i];
    }
    return $array;
}

$array_one = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g");

$array_two=index_shift($array_one, 3);

echo "<br />";
print_r($array_one);
print_r($array_two);
```